# Why does this regular expression match?

Tags: ruby, regex

```
"Galaxy".match(/(al)*/)
```

It seems that `<<>>Galaxy` is the match, where `<<>>` = matching part. Why is the R.E working? Perhaps because of `\b`?

RE:
 Sorry, it's my fault to post unclear question. 
Exactly, i want to know the reason that why the empty space is matched with (al)*.
Finally i could understand by you-all favor :)

Comment: Format your code properly, it's unclear what they are.

Comment: Cannot comprehend your first "sentence". What is R.E? ............

Comment: R.E. = regular expression. He is saying that it matches the word boundary at the beginning of the string, which happens because the regex he is using allows for empty matches.

Comment: @Surcae your question is unclear: the code is invalid (maybe you wanted to write `"Galaxy".match /(al)*/` or `"Galaxy" =~ /(al)*/` or `"Galaxy"[/(al)*/]`) and your regular expression doesn't even contain a `\b`.

Comment: @robertjlooby Look carefully. The OP hasn't written `R.E.` the OP has written `R.E`. Also, your edit changed the question. In the original question, the code was invalid. There is no method `./`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `/(al)*/` allows it to match nothing at all, which is what it does. It starts at the beginning of the string, matches "nothing" and returns. If you expected it to match the `al` in `Galaxy` then you would need to use `/(al)+/` to avoid empty matches.